# Why does 2.0 not fufill the requirements?

Tags: python-2.7

The numbers 1,10 and 2 all work but 2.0 does not

```
def get_number():
    number = 0
    while int(number) < 1 or int(number) > 10:
        if type(number) == str:
            pass``
        else:
            try:
                number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
            except:
                pass
    return float(number)
```

The output of 10 should be 10.0 and 1 should be 1.0 and 2.0 should output 2.0

Answer (score 0):

The reason this fails is because Python raises a `ValueError` when running your code against a *string representing a float*. See:

```
23:12 $ python
Python 2.7.15 (default, Mar  4 2019, 16:04:02)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> int('2.0')  # Note the string
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.0'
>>> int(2.0)  # Float
2
```

There's a lot of ways to improve your code, so I will leave you with this to ponder for now :-)

FYI: You originally tagged this as `python-3.x`, but your code was invalid for Python 3 due to the empty `except`. I'd recommend looking up best practices on exception handling as a further exercise.